# Is there something wrong with this jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there something wrong with this javascript and HTML? I am trying to make it so that when one of the `.tagSuggestTag` are clicked its value is inserted into the `<input>`, but for some reason it does nothing at all.

Javascript:

```
  $('.tagSuggestTag').click(
     function(){
       var currentTags = $('#testTags').val();
       var selectedTag = $(this).html();
       if (currentTags == "") {
           currentTags = selectedTag;
       } else {
           currentTags = currentTags + ", " + selectedTag;
       }
       $('#testTags').val(currentTags);
     });
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="testTags">
<ul>
    <li class="tagSuggestTag">test</li>
    <li class="tagSuggestTag">test2</li>
    <li class="tagSuggestTag">test3</li>
</ul>
```

UPDATE:
See full HTML here: http://pastebin.com/NyCz669u

I figured out what was wrong, I didn't say that the content in the `<ul>` was added by AJAX so I had forgot I needed to pass the `click` throught `.live()`

Comment: And? What happens? What’s the problem?

Comment: what's the problem ? what's happening ?

Comment: @Kissaki @Krtek nothing, it doesn't insert anything at all.

Comment: no error in javascript console or anything ? works greate in this jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/C9WQ5/

Comment: I tried your code in http://jsfiddle.net/ and it's working as you'd expect. Can you post the full html source?

Comment: @Scobal sure, heres the HTML: http://pastebin.com/NyCz669u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing wrong, the code [works just great](http://jsfiddle.net/3cbA8/).

Make sure you wrap it in a `$(document).ready`:

```
$(function() {
    $('.tagSuggestTag').click(function() {
        var currentTags = $('#testTags').val();
        var selectedTag = $(this).html();
        if (currentTags == "") {
            currentTags = selectedTag;
        } else {
            currentTags = currentTags + ", " + selectedTag;
        }
        $('#testTags').val(currentTags);
    });
});
```

Comment: hmm... thats weird, it used to work for me but now it doesn't must be somewhere else on the page..

Comment: @chromedude, did you wrap this code in a document.ready? Did you include the jQuery script? Did you check the FireBug console for errors?

Comment: yeah did all three, Im looking to see if there are any unclosed functions above it or something

Answer (score 1):

Chromedude: Make sure you're properly importing jQuery. Your code seems to work, look here:

http://jsfiddle.net/UqkKY/

Good luck,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

The error must be somewhere else, your code works great : http://jsfiddle.net/C9WQ5/

Answer (score 0):

There doesnt seem to be anything wrong with the JQuery code that you have presented. you just need to include $(document).ready() for initialization.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.tagSuggestTag').click(function () {
             var currentTags = $('#testTags').val();
             var selectedTag = $(this).html();
             if (currentTags == "") {
                 currentTags = selectedTag;
             } else {
                 currentTags = currentTags + ", " + selectedTag;
             }
             $('#testTags').val(currentTags);
        });
    });

</script>
```

Regards,
Junaid Mufti
[PioneeringDev](http://pioneeringdev.com)